# Grafana: How to display RAM by user / service

Tags: ubuntu, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, grafana-variable

So on one server, I run 2 nodes and I'm using node exporter to display RAM metrics on Grafana. The issue is that Grafana displays the total RAM usage from the server but I would like to display RAM usage for each node separately.

> node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~"$node"} - node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{instance=~"$node"}

How can I show only RAM from 1 node, for example only for one service (systemd) running, or split it by linux user?

Answer (score 0):

You can only filter labels that exist. For example, the following is possible when running on kubernetes:

`node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{cluster="..."}`

If there is no label for service systemd you can not filter it.
Therefore I am not sure that this metric can be used for your purpose.

You might try to add some collectors in the set_collectors section of the configuration. See [node exporter config](https://grafana.com/docs/agent/latest/configuration/integrations/node-exporter-config/) in the grafana documentation for a list of available collectors.