# Spark monitoring metrics, which one regards RAM utilization

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, grafana, metrics, graphite

I was wondering if there's a more detailed version of such spark webpage [Monitoring metrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)

Actually I'm using grafana and this is my dashboard, I'm not totally sure if we can assume the Heap usage as RAM usage.

[image: Grafana dashboard]

What I would like to achieve is to show the RAM used from each node and the total RAM available for each of them.

Any suggestion? I have a lot of different metrics I cannot report them all but we could continue the conversation in the comments (and then I'll add it in this topic for sake of clearance for the next developers interested)

I need help, monitoring metrics are not so well explained

Comment: Can you provide more details, like which environment you use *ApacheSpark* module when running PySpark scripts? There are some cloud-based envis such as [Databricks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/databricks/), which offer users to monitor the trend of allocation of recourses/running-threads as well as RAM in distributed systems when one runs the notebook.

Comment: Hi Mario sorry for the late reply, actually I've created on a VM a local standalone spark cluster made of 1 driver and 2 workers and I submit spark app through spark-submit. No I'm not using Databricks (I know it presents Ganglia for showing metrics)

Comment: Usually, cluster-based envi provide users with monitoring tools during the computation for resource consumption of (RAM) for the driver or distributed-based workers, along with the progress of the run with percentage metrics. I'm not familiar with _Grafana_. Have you checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73493136/grafana-how-to-display-ram-by-user-service?rq=1)?